# Wordpress SQL query the user's first & last name for product X?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, select, woocommerce

I am creating an SQL query where I want to display the full names and emails of customers who have purchased a downloadable product from a woocommerce shop. I am looking for something like this:

```
user_id    first_name    last_name    user_email    order
---------------------------------------------------------
1          Peter         Jones        a12@gmail     Doc_1
```

In the table above, **Doc_1** stands for the name of the product, in this case the customer with **user_id = 1** can download **Doc_1**. For wordpress users, you know that the table `wp_usermeta` contains all the user's information, and looks like this:

```
umeta_id    user_id    meta_key    meta_value
---------------------------------------------
1           1          nickname    petjon123
2           1          first_name  Peter
3           1          last_name   Jones
...         ...        ...         ...
```

This list goes down containing more `meta_value[s]` including email, etc. Everything would have been much more easier if the `meta_key[s]` would be table headers showing `first_name` and `last_name` beside each other instead of on top one another. I have come this far where my query shows the `first_name`, but I am having trouble getting the `last_name`. My SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  wp_usermeta.user_id,
  wp_usermeta.meta_value AS 'first_name',
  Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1.user_email AS 'email',
  Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1.order_item_name AS 'order'
FROM Wp_woocommerce_order_items
     INNER JOIN Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
       ON Wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions.order_id,
     (Wp_woocommerce_order_items AS Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1
     INNER JOIN Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions AS Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1
       ON Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1.order_id = Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1.order_id)
     INNER JOIN wp_usermeta
       ON Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1.user_id = wp_usermeta.user_id
GROUP BY wp_usermeta.user_id,
         wp_usermeta.meta_value,
         Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1.user_email,
         Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1.order_item_name,
         Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1.order_item_type,
         wp_usermeta.meta_key
HAVING (((Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1.order_item_type) = 'line_item')
AND ((wp_usermeta.meta_key) = 'first_name'));
```

Giving me this result:

```
user_id    first_name    user_email    order
--------------------------------------------
1          Peter         a12@gmail     Doc_1
```

I checked these values manually, and they are correct, however, I must say that if I do not **GROUP** the results, I get 1000 times more results, so **GROUPING** the data simplifies the results by basically removing the duplicates which obviously is excessive. I am doubting that this query is efficient given that the execution time until the results appear is +/-**20368.14 ms** and hereby am very open to any suggestions of improving this code. Having this said, I thought that I had to do another query to get the `last_name` making this a **NESTED QUERY**. If I open the tables in MS Access, create lets say **Query1** which is the query above, and join **Query1** with the table I get the results that I want. The SQL code for this is as follows:

```
SELECT
  Query1.user_id,
  Query1.first_name,
  wp_usermeta.meta_value AS 'last_name',
  Query1.user_email,
  Query1.order_item_name
FROM wp_usermeta
INNER JOIN Query1
  ON wp_usermeta.user_id = Query1.user_id
WHERE (((wp_usermeta.meta_value) <> '')
AND ((wp_usermeta.meta_key) = 'last_name'));
```

I tried substituting **Query1** for this second query using parenthesis by enclosing the code from **Query1**, and this did not work. I get this error:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.user_id, (SELECT wp_usermeta.user_id, wp_usermeta.meta_value AS 'first' at line 22*

Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks!!

---

**UPDATE**

According to the answer provided by @Hogan I came up with this:

```
SELECT
  first.user_id,
  first.meta_value AS 'first_name',
  last.meta_value AS 'last_name',
  Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1.user_email,
  Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1.order_item_name
FROM Wp_woocommerce_order_items
     INNER JOIN Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
       ON Wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions.order_id,
     wp_usermeta AS last
     INNER JOIN ((Wp_woocommerce_order_items AS Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1
     INNER JOIN Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions AS Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1
       ON Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1.order_id = Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1.order_id)
     INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS first
       ON Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1.user_id = first.user_id)
       ON last.user_id = Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1.user_id
GROUP BY first.user_id,
         first.meta_value,
         last.meta_value,
         Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1.user_email,
         Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1.order_item_name,
         Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1.order_item_type,
         first.meta_key,
         last.meta_key
HAVING (((Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1.order_item_type) = 'line_item')
AND ((first.meta_key) = 'first_name')
AND ((last.meta_key) = 'last_name'));
```

Which works perfectly fine in MS Access but in SQL it does not. I am getting this error:

*Unknown column 'first.meta_key' in 'having clause'*

Why?

I also have to mention, that when I add the `meta_key[s]` to the `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT
  first.user_id,
  first.meta_value AS 'first_name',
  last.meta_value AS 'last_name',
  Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1.user_email,
  Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1.order_item_name,
  first.meta_key,
  last.meta_key
```

I at least get no error, the query is running but it goes on and on increasing my CPU usage drastically given that I am working on a localhost.

---

**SOLUTION**

`SELECT DISTINCT` did the trick. No **GROUPING**. The query results appear in **127.76 ms**. This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  first.user_id AS 'id',
  first.meta_value AS 'first_name',
  last.meta_value AS 'last_name',
  Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1.user_email AS 'email',
  Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1.order_item_name AS 'order'
FROM Wp_woocommerce_order_items
     INNER JOIN Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
       ON Wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions.order_id,
     ((Wp_woocommerce_order_items AS Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1
     INNER JOIN Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions AS Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1
       ON Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1.order_id = Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1.order_id)
     INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS first
       ON Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1.user_id = first.user_id)
     INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS last
       ON Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1.user_id = last.user_id
WHERE (((first.meta_key) = 'first_name')
AND ((last.meta_key) = 'last_name')
AND ((Wp_woocommerce_order_items_1.order_item_type) = 'line_item'));
```

As @Hogan stated, simply add the table `wp_usermeta` again with another alias, and make an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: As an aside, your query assumes that all meta keys are populated. This may well be true for things like first name and last name, but might not be the case for other meta keys - in which case an INNER JOIN will omit that customer, and an OUTER JOIN should be used instead.

Comment: Those look nothing like my queries.  I never put `first.meta_key = 'first_name'` in the `HAVING` clause or in the `WHERE` or between that many parenthesis.   Seriously get rid of all of the parenthesis, this is not algebra they don't matter.   Put those in the join like I did, it will make your query faster and clearer.

Comment: @Hogan Ok. I will do so. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this join

```
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS last 
    ON Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions_1.user_id = last.user_id AND last.meta_key = 'last_name'
```

and the column

```
last.meta_value AS 'last_name',
```

You probably don't need to go so crazy with the `()` -- order does not matter unless you are doing a sub query (which you aren't) or are mixing left and right joins (which you aren't).

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Where do I add this code? I am constantly getting syntax errors. Could you provide the whole query so that I have an overview? Thanks once again :)

Comment: I don't have an mysql to test my syntax and a fire came up here -- I'll give it a shot in a few mins if I can find these 1.6 million missing rows.

Comment: @AvaBarbilla looks like aaron D has you covered.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  pp.user_id,
  first.meta_value AS 'first_name',
  last.meta_value AS 'last_name',
  pp.user_email AS 'email',
  oi.order_item_name AS 'order'
FROM
  Wp_woocommerce_order_items oi
INNER JOIN
  Wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions pp ON pp.order_id = oi.order_id
INNER JOIN
  wp_usermeta first ON first.user_id = pp.user_id
INNER JOIN
  wp_usermeta last ON last.user_id = pp.user_id
WHERE first.meta_key = 'first_name'
AND last.meta_key = 'last_name'
AND oi.order_item_type = 'line_item'
```

Comment: I pasted the code inside into My Web SQL and it did not work. I'm getting: _Unknown column 'wo.order_item_name' in 'field list'_

Comment: @AvaBarbilla Whoops, wrong alias.  Fixed, but it looks like you got it working :D